# I cannot access Source Code Pro font in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: fonts, editing, visual-studio-2022

I recently downloaded and installed Visual Studio 2022 professional and then tried to change the editing font to `Source Code Pro` but the IDE does not list it as an alternative. I have Source Code Pro font installed on my system because I use the font in `Pycharm IDE`. What can I do so that the font gets to be listed by this IDE?, previous versions of Visual Studio had that font. Thank You.

Comment: You could try to install again the Source Code Pro font, including all the `.ttf` variants, then reboot.

Comment: Did you install the font *per user* or available to all users? See https://borncity.com/win/2020/05/15/windows-server-2019-font-install-per-user-or-system-wide/ for example.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve this by installing the TTF font of Source Code Pro from [this github repo](https://github.com/adobe-fonts/source-code-pro/releases/tag/2.038R-ro/1.058R-it/1.018R-VAR).